# Excel VBA & MYSQL's Select LAST_INSERT_ID();

Tags: mysql, excel, vba

I have code that takes data out of my workbook and loads it into an SQL database.  It's working just fine, but I just realized that once I insert something and a primary key is generated for that line, I want to add that back into my excel workbook so that I can run update statements against them.

In SQL, I know I can run

```
Insert into reports (blah, blah, blah, etc...)
Values (1,2,3, etc....)
Select LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

and get the primary key for the new row I just inserted, but I can't figure out how to get the output of that Select LAST_INSERT_ID(); back into Excel....

My code looks like this:

```
SQLINSERT = "Insert into `dwInvoice`.`report` (`TrackNumber`, `RegNSB`, `TrackCount`, `TrackNSB`, `TotalBacklog`, `AverageBacklogTrackMargin`, `RegRGP`, `RGPPercent`, `PriceCode`, `PMName`, `PMComments`, `PMMRecommendations`, `Outcome`, `NewGPPercent`, `AdditionalGP`, `HomeBranch`, `HomeBranchCode`, `BranchCode`, `PMM`, `FSRName`, `SMRName`, `DateReport`, `NEDA`, `NEDAName`, `HomeNEDA`, `HomeNEDAName`, `InvCustEB`, `InvCustNum`, `InvCustName`, `InvCustDWIndicator`, `RegNum`, `AppDate`, `InvoiceDate`, `InvoiceNumber`, `PartNumber`, `DWCustEB`, `DWCustNumb`, `DWCustName`, `DWIndicator`, `DRAWstatus`, `MarginType`, `UnitResale`, `UnitCost`, `PriceCost`, `UnitsShipped`, `TeamNum`, `TeamName`, `IndirectCustNum`, `IndirectCustDWCode`, `IndirectCustEB`, `IndirectCustName`) VALUES("
SQLOUTPUT = "Select LAST_INSERT_ID()"

For Each c In Range("A2:A" & lastRow)
SQLBODY = "'" & c.Value & "','" & c.Offset(0, 1).Value & "','" & c.Offset(0, 2).Value & "','" & c.Offset(0, 3).Value & "','" & c.Offset(0, 4).Value & "','" & c.Offset(0, 5).Value & "','" & c.Offset(0, 6).Value & "','" & c.Offset(0, 7).Value & "','" & c.Offset(0, 8).Value & "','" & c.Offset(0, 9).Value & "','" & c.Offset(0, 10).Value & "','" & c.Offset(0, 11).Value & "','" & c.Offset(0, 12).Value & "','" & c.Offset(0, 13).Value & "','" & c.Offset(0, 14).Value & "','" & c.Offset(0, 15).Value & "','" & c.Offset(0, 16).Value & "','" & c.Offset(0, 17).Value & "','" & c.Offset(0, 18).Value & "','" & c.Offset(0, 19).Value & "','" & c.Offset(0, 20).Value & "','" & c.Offset(0, 21).Value & "','" & c.Offset(0, 22).Value & "','" & c.Offset(0, 23).Value & "','" & c.Offset(0, 24).Value & "','" & c.Offset(0, 25).Value & "','" & c.Offset(0, 26).Value & "','" _
        & c.Offset(0, 27).Value & "','" & c.Offset(0, 28).Value & "','" & c.Offset(0, 29).Value & "','" & c.Offset(0, 30).Value & "','" & c.Offset(0, 31).Value & "','" & c.Offset(0, 32).Value & "','" & c.Offset(0, 33).Value & "','" & c.Offset(0, 34).Value & "','" & c.Offset(0, 35).Value & "','" & c.Offset(0, 36).Value & "','" & c.Offset(0, 37).Value & "','" & c.Offset(0, 38).Value & "','" & c.Offset(0, 39).Value & "','" & c.Offset(0, 40).Value & "','" & c.Offset(0, 41).Value & "','" & c.Offset(0, 42).Value & "','" & c.Offset(0, 43).Value & "','" & c.Offset(0, 44).Value & "','" & c.Offset(0, 45).Value & "','" & c.Offset(0, 46).Value & "','" & c.Offset(0, 47).Value & "','" & c.Offset(0, 48).Value & "','" & c.Offset(0, 49).Value & "','" & c.Offset(0, 50).Value & "')"
SQLEND = ";"

SQL_GET = "" & SQLIF & SQLINSERT & SQLBODY & SQLEND
cmd.CommandText = SQL_GET
Set rs = cmd.Execute
next c
```

I know this is long... but it works.

I can modify the statement changing SQL_GET to:

```
    SQL_GET = "" & SQLIF & SQLINSERT & SQLBODY & SQLEND & SQLOUTPUT & SQLEND
```

to add the `Select LAST_INSERT_ID() ;` to the end of the SQL statement, but I still have no idea how to actually GET that value that is output back INTO Excel.  Any ideas on how to get this to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `Set rs = cmd.Execute` put the following:

```
rs.open SQLOUTPUT

'to dump the recordset into a worksheet range:
Sheet1.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordSet rs

`to dump the result into a variable:
Dim lastInsertID as string
lastInsertID = rs.Fields(1).value
```

Comment: First - thank you!  I will (attempt) to test that out soon.  For now, I'm getting the following error:

`System Msg:[MySQL][ODBC 5.3(w) Driver][mysqld-5.6.20]You have an error in SQL syntax near 'Select LAST_INSERT_ID()' at line 1`

The syntax is exactly how I would type it into an actual SQL query....

Comment: Oh nevermind - I just ran it without the SQLOUTPUT on the end of the original query, then ran this code you provided.  Thank you so much!